# iPhone Xcode PDF MAP location GPS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, dictionary, gps

I have a PDF map. What's the easiest way, to add a GPS "blue dot" with my location. Somehow to sync it with maps & add this PDF as a layer on top of that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a post on rendering a PDF to PNG. [How to convert PDF to PNG efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45775394/how-to-convert-pdf-to-png-efficiently)

You'll need to know the GPS coordinates at the top left and bottom right of the image that produces.

You can try creating an MKOverlay containing the image and define its MKMapRect based on those known coordinates.

If that doesn't work for some reason, you could use MKMapView's convert(_:toPointTo:) to tell you where those GPS coordinates are on a UIView that you manage yourself. (Heads up: that's more complicated than it seems)